# Flutter Speech Recognition : how to get a percentage of "similarity" between the right pronunciation of a word and the user's pronunciation

Tags: flutter, speech-recognition

As stated in the question : I am developing an app for French kids to learn English vocabulary. I have added a SpeechToText functionality using the SpeechToText package, which really works well.
However, I am hitting a hard rock now... One of the activities proposed to the students is simply "Listen and repeat", so that they progressively improve their pronunciation.
I thought of using the SpeechToText package as well for this... and it would work if the students pronounced the words quite well.... One example : The sound "TH" for a French speaker is problematic and is very often pronounced as a "Z"... so the app never really recognize a word like "Father"... it keeps thinking the user says "Fazza".
Is there a way to compare the "good pronunciation" of a word to what the user says... get a percentage of "similitude". I know we can compare strings that way.

Would anyone know of a solution for this issue ? Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [speechace](https://www.speechace.com/) APIs to get the following features:

1. Pronunciation Assessment
2. Fluency Assessment
3. Spontaneous speech assessment